# Unit Testing on U-SQL Procedures

Tags: unit-testing, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am trying to figure out how to write and perform U-SQL Unit Testing on U-SQL Procedures. Do you have an example or template?

Answer (score 2):

Zirui,
currently you can use the U-SQL SDK to run script locally as a way to do unit test.  Here is a user guide of the SDK.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-sdk

And the SDK is here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK/

To make your cases self contained, you can create input data by VALUES Table Value Constructor:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621292.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396